# Counting function evaluations

Tags: openmdao

I just finished the tutorial on reader and recorder. And I was wondering if there was a way to count the number of times each discipline is called. Below I use global variables to count this in Sellar problem. What would be a better way to do this ? Also if there is no solver in the problem, will the suggested way change ?

```python
import numpy as np
import time
import openmdao.api as om

tic = time.perf_counter()
dc1 = 0
dc2 = 0

class SellarDis1(om.ExplicitComponent):
    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('z', val=np.zeros(2))
        self.add_input('x', val=0.)
        self.add_input('y2', val=1.0)
        self.add_output('y1', val=1.0)
        self.declare_partials('*', '*', method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        global dc1
        dc1+=1
        z1 = inputs['z'][0]
        z2 = inputs['z'][1]
        x1 = inputs['x']
        y2 = inputs['y2']
        outputs['y1'] = z1**2 + z2 + x1 - 0.2*y2

class SellarDis2(om.ExplicitComponent):

    def setup(self):
        self.add_input('z', val=np.zeros(2))
        self.add_input('y1', val=1.0)
        self.add_output('y2', val=1.0)
        self.declare_partials('*', '*',method='fd')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):
        global dc2
        dc2 +=1
        z1 = inputs['z'][0]
        z2 = inputs['z'][1]
        y1 = inputs['y1']
        if y1.real < 0.0:
            y1 *= -1
        outputs['y2'] = y1**.5 + z1 + z2

class SellarMDF(om.Group):
    def setup(self):
        indeps = self.add_subsystem('indeps', om.IndepVarComp(), promotes=['*'])
        indeps.add_output('x', 1.0)
        indeps.add_output('z', np.array([5.0, 2.0]))

        cycle = self.add_subsystem('cycle', om.Group(), promotes=['*'])
        cycle.add_subsystem('d1', SellarDis1(), promotes_inputs=['x', 'z', 'y2'],
                            promotes_outputs=['y1'])
        cycle.add_subsystem('d2', SellarDis2(), promotes_inputs=['z', 'y1'],
                            promotes_outputs=['y2'])

        cycle.linear_solver = om.ScipyKrylov()

        cycle.nonlinear_solver = om.NewtonSolver(solve_subsystems=False)
        

        self.add_subsystem('obj_cmp', om.ExecComp('obj = x**2 + z[1] + y1 + exp(-y2)',
                                                  z=np.array([0.0, 0.0]), x=0.0, y1=0.0, y2=0.0),
                           promotes=['x', 'z', 'y1', 'y2', 'obj'])

        self.add_subsystem('con_cmp1', om.ExecComp('con1 = 3.16 - y1'), promotes=['con1', 'y1'])
        self.add_subsystem('con_cmp2', om.ExecComp('con2 = y2 - 24.0'), promotes=['con2', 'y2'])

prob = om.Problem()
prob.model = SellarMDF()

driver = prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizer()
prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'

prob.model.add_design_var('x', lower=0, upper=10)
prob.model.add_design_var('z', lower=0, upper=10)

prob.model.add_objective('obj')
prob.model.add_constraint('con1', upper=0)
prob.model.add_constraint('con2', upper=0)
prob.setup()
prob.set_solver_print(level=0)

prob.run_driver()

print('minimum found at')
print(prob['x'][0])
print(prob['z'])

print('Coupling Variables')
print(prob['y1'][0])
print(prob['y2'][0])

print('minumum objective')
print(prob['obj'][0])

toc = time.perf_counter()
print(f"You waited {toc - tic:0.4f} seconds")
print("Function Calls")
print('SellarDis1 : ', dc1)
print('SellarDis2 : ', dc2)
```

Edit: By better I mean "openmdao" way, like with recorder or something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All OpenMDAO systems (the umbrella term for components and groups) have the `iter_count` attribute. Here is the [documentation page for `System`](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/_srcdocs/packages/core/system.html#openmdao.core.system.System), from which all components and groups inherit from. `iter_count` is the total number of calls to each `compute()` method, whereas `iter_count_without_approx` is the number of calls to the `compute()` method without including those due to gradient approximation. This method works for any solver hierarchy or driver setup.

The last two lines of your sample script would thus be:

```
print('SellarDis1 : ', prob.model.cycle.d1.iter_count)
print('SellarDis2 : ', prob.model.cycle.d2.iter_count)
```

This doesn't use the recorder, as you suggested. If you instead prefer a solution that uses the recorder, we can find a workable method. There's a lot of flexibility there and to get started you can check out [this specific doc page on case reading](http://openmdao.org/twodocs/versions/latest/features/recording/reading_data.html#getting-variable-data-from-case-recording-of-a-problem), which could help postprocess a case to get the total number of calls.

Please let me know if anything's unclear!

Comment: Thank you for your time. This exactly what I was looking for. The count when I use global variables is `SellarDis1 :  111, SellarDis2 :  89` and when I use `iter_count` it is `SellarDis1 :  64, SellarDis2 :  48`. Do you know what causes this huge difference ?

Comment: I don't have a good answer for that. I checked on my machine and I got the same results as you. If you change the nonlinear solver to NonlinearBlockGS, there's still a discrepancy, so I don't think it's related to the type of solver. I reached out to the OpenMDAO dev team and they're looking into it.

Comment: And here's their corresponding issue: https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/issues/1651

Comment: I can address the difference.  iter_count only counts the number of times that `solve_nonlinear` is called.  On an ExplicitComponent, `apply_nonlinear` also calls compute. This is because, to calculate the norm of the residual for the current set of inputs and outputs, you need to run the component again, and the residual is the change in outputs.  This is definitely confusing though. To clear things up, we decided to add another counter that keeps track of the number of times `apply_nonlinear` is called. To get the total executes, you would sum iter_count and iter_count_apply. (cont.)

Comment: This new counter will be available in OpenMDAO versions 3.2.2 onward.

Answer (score 1):

Coverage tools like [Coverage](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/) or [PyTest-Cov](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/) can use hooks in the python interpreter to collect data about which code is running when during your program's execution, which often includes the number of "hits" per function or even individual lines. If you just want the numbers outside the program, this might already be enough for you.

If you need the numbers for use in the script itself, you can use some of the underlying APIs yourself. With [sys.settrace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html?highlight=settrace#sys.settrace) you can register a function to be called on every function call in your program. The first argument to that function will be a [frame object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#frame-objects), which contains attributes you can use to check if this is the function you're interested in.

Here's a short example:

```py
import sys

class A:
    def my_func(self, x):
        return x + 1

my_func_calls = 0

def tracefunc(frame, event, arg):
    global my_func_calls
    if event == 'call' and frame.f_code.co_name == 'my_func':
        my_func_calls += 1

sys.settrace(tracefunc)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = A()
    x = a.my_func(0)
    x = a.my_func(x)
    x = a.my_func(x)
    print("my_func_calls:", my_func_calls)
```

Since I don't see any way to get the actual function object associated with (which would give you the class using `__self__.__class__`), you may need to use `frame.co_firstlineno` to distinguish methods with the same name.

The nitty gritty details of this trace function are a bit tricky, you can reference [coverage.py's implementation](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/4876f170e5d59b8a45ae0c6732acb73b8ac566d2/coverage/pytracer.py#L81) for inspiration on your options and possible problems.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know about this and it is helpful. However, I was hoping for something by using any Openmdao function. I only need the count outside the program. But I am not able to use global variables because I have two different files, each containing multiple classes (explicit component) and a group. I have a third file where I connect all into a top level group. Also the function name is "compute" in all the classes so `settrace` might not work. So what I want to ask is, if it is possible to somehow do the count in an openmdao-ish way (by recorder or some other in built function).